# Entire PDF document as appendix

Tags: graphics, pdf, include

I'm writing a report, where I need to include some large PDF files as the appendix. I tried using this command:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.75]{myfile.pdf}[H]
```

In the `pdfpages` package, but it seems to work as a copy of the PDF. In stead I need to include the PDF *content*. This way, the styling of the original document is kept, and it's clear that the included file is a seperate document.

EDIT: To clarify, The mother-document should not lose it's styling. This includes header, footer, page numbering etc. The included PDF document should be split up, such that each page is compressed a little, to accommodate for this, so that it's clear that the included page is just that - included. I also intend to wrap the content of each included PDF fil,e in a small frame or similar. Hope this clarifies.

I also tried using `\includegraphics`, but this doesn't seem to be allowed to span several pages.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. A pdf file is already typeset so line breaking fonts colours etc are fixed you can not include it and inherit the styling of the current docuemnt. Also what is `[H]` doing?

Comment: the best you can do is to make your currente document style as the pdf style.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify. `[H]` is used to anchor the document, to where it's placed, i.e. included where I decide it is, and not where Latex thinks it's best.

Comment: no need for [H]

Comment: you can use the `pagecommand` key to set the pagestyle and you can scale the pages, see the   documentation of includepdf.

Comment: Just a complete different solution: Include the pdfs with [attachfile](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/attachfile) in your appendix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resovle the issue with the following command. (Credits to  Ulrike Fischer, for pointing me in the right direction)

```
\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=0.8,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},frame]{myfile.pdf}
```