# includepdf output just white page with some pdf files

Tags: pdfpages, blank-page

I'm using the Arsclassica template for my thesis and at the end I would like to attach some pdf files (ie a research paper, my CV, declaration of originality). Using `\includepdf` works for the pdf of my CV (created with latex) but instead of adding the paper and the declaration files it is just putting the corresponding number of white pages.

These are the settings in the main .tex file, at the end the `\includepdf` files

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%draft,%
               10pt,%
               a4paper, %twoside,%
               openright,%
               titlepage,fleqn,headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
               numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
               tablecaptionabove]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[italian,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % Coloured text etc.
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\input{arsclassica-settings}

\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage,smaller]{acronym} % acronyms

\bibliography{ThesisBibliography}

\usepackage{makeidx}                        % analitycal index

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%******************************************************************%
% Frontmatter
%******************************************************************%
\include{FrontBackMatter/Titlepage}
\include{FrontBackMatter/Titleback}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearpage
\include{FrontBackMatter/Contents}
\include{FrontBackMatter/Abstract}
\cleardoublepage
%******************************************************************%
% Mainmatter
%******************************************************************%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Chapters/1}
% *****************************************************************%
% Backmatter
%******************************************************************%
\clearpage
\include{FrontBackMatter/Acronyms}
\clearpage
\include{FrontBackMatter/Bibliography}
\clearpage
\include{FrontBackMatter/Index}
\clearpage

\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1,chapter,1,{Article1},Art1}]{Appendix/Article1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1,chapter,1,{Curriculum Vitae},CV}]{Appendix/CV.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1,chapter,1,{Declaration of Originality},DeclOrig}]{Appendix/DeclarationOriginality.pdf}
\end{document}
```

After compiling everything is correct, no error messages in the log file. In the pdf output all good except for the pages corresponding to Article1 and DeclarationOriginality.pdf:

I get (complete thesis)+(article1.pdf white pages)+(proper CV.pdf)+(DeclOrig.pdf white page)

The most strange thing to me is that with the CV.pdf file I have no problems (maybe because was created with LaTex?)

I tried to

1. open and save the other pdfs with different pdf readers
2. load them as graphics with `\includegraphics`

   - I don't see it but if I cross over the command with the mouse I get the first page picture overview of the pdf
3. add scale factor to 0.8 in `\includepdf[]` options as in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239450/entire-pdf-document-as-appendix)
4. include just single pages
5. reset background color (following the suggestion I found from another question in TeXexchange)

without positive results.

My ideas start to be over so **my question for the community** is:

Is there an already known issue/solution for `\includepdf` command giving just white pages with "random" pdf input files?

Comment: How were the problematic PDFs created? What does `pdfinfo` say? Are fonts embedded? Anything in the `.log`? How large are these files? Which viewer?

Comment: Article1 is a normal pdf downloaded from online newspaper website [Article1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0969996117301584?via%3Dihub); the other is a pdf with some fields to fill from the university [DeclOrig](http://www.gcb.unibe.ch/e126792/e289326/e314253/files315565/Declaration_of_Originality_eng.pdf). In the `.log` no errors declared, (I can copy paste the log section regarding the `\includepdf` but is long for a comment). The files size are: Article1=1.6MB; CV=102.6kB; DeclOrig=204.9kB. I tried to save both with PDFXChange Viewer and Xreader (in linux)

Comment: Regarding the pdf with some forms to fill: Does your pdf reader have the ability to turn off scripting in the pdf? If so, turn off scripting, then load that pdf by itself. What does it show? There is a tiny chance that the visible content is scripted, and that the script is not active when you include that pdf in the larger document.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this problem probably can't be reproduced, hence not be solved, after such a long time.